# Crawling a page that uses a hash tag in the URL

Tags: webkit, web-crawler, phantomjs, headless-browser

I'm building a tool that fetches some basic metadata about a site (the same amount that Facebook does when you try to share a link): the title, description and the primary image. This is fairly simple for HTML pages with [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/), [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or a host of other tools out there.

How about pages that use ajax heavily, though? Some sites, especially the ones that use hash fragments may respond to the [Google AJAX crawling standard](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174992) and work with `_escaped_fragment_`, but I don't think that's the majority.

Is there any slightly scalable solution that uses [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or headless Chrome / Webkit to set up a crawl farm? Or is there an another way to headlessly execute JS and pull out the resulting HTML?

Bonus points for a tool that supports screenshots :D